# Why I can not import the package in Python?

Tags: python, import, package

I use the code from here:
https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python

And every time I try to import the file folder, `import got`, it will raise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\python\get_old_tweet\Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import got
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\python\get_old_tweet\got\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import models
ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

I have check the file and been pretty sure that they do have the file folder called `models`

And the file folder also contains `__init__.py` file.

So it should work well..

I have no idea how it doesn't work. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Python do you use?

The library https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python is written with Python 2.
Python 2 and Python 3 have a bit different behavior with import: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/#imports

Let me share example of import regarding your case:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 14:39:26)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import got
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/viach/Downloads/GetOldTweets-python-master/got/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import models
ImportError: No module named 'models'
>>> ^C
KeyboardInterrupt

$ python2
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import got
```

So, **quick solution** for you: use Python 2 in your app which depends on `GetOldTweets-python`.

Comment: You are correct. I rewrite the package to fit Python 3 and it finally works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are importing from. In the repository you proved a link to `models` is a subfolder of `got`. Try this:

```
from got import models
```

Comment: If the Python module 'models.py' is in the sub directory 'got' you should add an empty file called '__init__.py' in the 'got' directory then the 'from got import models' should work.

Answer (score 0):

Python only searches its default library paths by default (including the running script path). So you need to put them in Python default library paths or append your module path to those paths.

To append the path array:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("path/to/the_module")
>>> import the_module
```

If above solution doesn't worked, try:

```
>>> from models import got
```

Comment: really appreciate for your help. But this does not work either.... Still raise `ImportError`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Python3-compatible fork of GetOldTweets-python:
https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets-python3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)